# GitHub API - Get the branches of all repos in a team

Tags: git, github, access-token, github-api

We are planning to do a clean up of all the branches in our repos and hence I am trying to get the list of branches for all the repos in our team.
I am able to successfully  get the repos list using github api but getting a "Bad credentials" error

I got the team Repos using below cmd, and it worked fine:

`curl -H "Authorization: token <PERSONALACCESSTOKEN>" -X GET https://api.github.com/teams/:team_id/repos`

Tying to get branches in a repo using

`curl -H "Authorization: token <PERSONALACCESSTOKEN>" -X GET https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/:repo/branches`

I am using same `<PERSONALACCESSTOKEN>` for the above 2 commands but getting the below error

`{
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, its because I am not the admin. Only admin/owner of repo can list branches. Once I replaced member token with admin's token, it worked.